# Anything cheaper or better than getting a car from a rental place in Spain?

Tags: budget, car-rentals, spain

I'm hoping to make a road trip in Spain in August. Since I'll be driving alot, I want to minimize what I pay for the car rental.

Is there any better option than getting a car from a rent-a-car? Does something like Airbnb for cars exist?

Any super cheap rent-a-cars in Spain that aren't listed in popular travel booking sites?

Thanks!

Comment: [BlaBlaCar](https://www.blablacar.es/) for car sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I came back from the trip and have found some answers:

As stated in a comment, [BlaBlaCar](http://BlaBlaCar.es) is super popular in Spain. I found that sometimes it's not cheaper than a bus or train, but probably more convenient.

Also [Drivy](https://www.drivy.com/) exists, which is a service in which people rent their cars. I didn't actually use it since I read that they only accept EU drivers licenses (unconfirmed though)

Comment: I was in Spain last year and spent less than 200 EU renting a vehicle for a whole week from a rental place.  The deal came through Ryanair.  You can probably find it cheaper if you carry your own insurance as offered by certain credit cards, or even your own car's insurance company.